Error Unable to start debugging on the web server
I have an ASP.NET website running on Win 10 Enterprise, .NET 4.8 and IIS 10. When I open the website in VS 2022 and try to debug an .aspx webforms page, I get a message

Unable to start debugging on the server. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80004005

VS is using local IIS to run the website. This is happening on my development machine. Both VS and IIS are running with administrator privileges.
This is in the web.config for the site:
<compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.8">

What can I do so that I can debug pages of this website?

You need to first review all project settings related https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/vs-diagnostics

Check bit size- is iis running as x64, but your site as x32?

1. Source code and IIS deployment directory are same
If you have placed the source code in a directory c:\testdirectory
and pointed the IIS to above directory
and opened the code from the same directory

Keep the source code directory and IIS directory separate & debug from source code directory.

You cant use the same directory because IIS 10 and IIS Express conflict, maybe they try to generate the .dll at the same time (I suspect)
2. Trying to debug already deployed code, my site is production environment
From a separate source code directory, open the source code in visual studio, 
Add debug pointer in your source code file
Go to Debug menu in Visual studioDebug => Attach to process => Select all w2wp.exe instances
The debugger is about to have a 'moment' with the breakpoint when you reload the page
PS:

Make sure you have deployed latest publish files to IIS 10 otherwise breakpoint wont hit
You can do remote debugging in VS too, no need to open prod environment


Attaching to w3wp.exe worked. This is on dev machine and not production.  It's a pain to reattach to this process every time I have to debug but it let's me debug.

The problem may be caused by url rewrite module. You can test a basic web.config file with no URL rewrites.
You can find a detailed classification of this problem here, I think it should be useful for you：Operation not supported. Unknown error: errornumber
But if this still not work, you can try run command iisreset.
